# How do I convert binary to ASCII in python without it giving me output in another language?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that converts text to binary and from binary to text. English to binary works perfectly fine, converting binary back always gives me another language.

````
    x = input("Encrypt: ")
    y = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in x)
    print("Encrypted message: " + str(y))
    encryptDecrypt()


def converttotext():
    a = input("Decrypt: ")
    a = a.split(" ")
    b = ""
    for binary_value in a:
        c = int(binary_value, 2)
        d = chr(c)
        b += d
    print(b)
    encryptDecrypt()


def encryptDecrypt():
    e = input("Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): ")
    if e == "e":
        converttobinary()
    elif e == "d":
        converttotext()
    else:
        print("Enter 'e' or 'd'.")
        encryptDecrypt()


def main():
    encryptDecrypt()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
Here is the run log:
Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): e
Encrypt: hi
Encrypted message: 11010001101001
Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): d
Decrypt: 11010001101001
㑩
Encrypt or decrypt(e/d):
````

Comment: where is the code for `converttobinary()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing putting a space between each 8 bit output for each char you encrypt, your join in convert to binary should be with a space not with an empty string. Your decryption method is splitting the input by space expecting each char to be a separate 8 bit string. However your encrypt message just joins all the bits together giving you a 16 bit string by joining the 2 8 bit strings of "H" and "I" together. Decryption that 16 bit will give you a different result to decrypting the two 8 bit chars.

change

```
    y = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in x)
```

to

```
    y = ' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in x)
```

**CODE I AM RUNNING**

```py
def converttobinary():
    x = input("Encrypt: ")
    y = ' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in x)
    print("Encrypted message: " + str(y))


def converttotext():
    a = input("Decrypt: ")
    a = a.split(" ")
    b = ""
    for binary_value in a:
        c = int(binary_value, 2)
        d = chr(c)
        b += d
    print(b)


def encryptDecrypt():
    e = input("Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): ")
    if e == "e":
        converttobinary()
    elif e == "d":
        converttotext()
    else:
        print("Enter 'e' or 'd'.")


def main():
    while True:
        encryptDecrypt()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): e
Encrypt: hi
Encrypted message: 1101000 1101001
Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): d
Decrypt: 1101000 1101001
hi

Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): e
Encrypt: How's the weather today
Encrypted message: 1001000 1101111 1110111 100111 1110011 100000 1110100 1101000 1100101 100000 1110111 1100101 1100001 1110100 1101000 1100101 1110010 100000 1110100 1101111 1100100 1100001 1111001
Encrypt or decrypt(e/d): d
Decrypt: 1001000 1101111 1110111 100111 1110011 100000 1110100 1101000 1100101 100000 1110111 1100101 1100001 1110100 1101000 1100101 1110010 100000 1110100 1101111 1100100 1100001 1111001
How's the weather today
```

Comment: I got an error message saying ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '100111 1'

Comment: For what string, i have copied your code and only thing i changed was adding a space for the join

Comment: "How's the weather today?"

Comment: did you copy the binary wrong, I have updated my answer to show "how's the weather today" works for me

Comment: I copied the output exactly as it is. I have also experimented around a bit, and apparently anything over 8 characters causes weird things to happen. Also, maybe it's because we have different versions of python? I'm on 3.8, using PyCharm

Comment: I also ran on 3.8 on pycharm. Updating the answer with the full code.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1THTmlcAGTpdV38CzvgxABwYa1aJFaXbI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your convert to text isnt the same as the code you pasted or the code i pasted. In your original post and in my code convert to text splits by space. In the screen shot you have it looks like you are trying to slice from a variable z using i to i+8 to get 8 bits. However in your current to binary your not assuring that all binary outputs will be a fixed length of bits. look at your output some of them are 7 bits and some 6 bits, so you are ending up taking 8 bits where one is a 6 bit and then a space then the first bit of the next char

Comment: You need to either update your question with your actual code or update your code using the code in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I was running a copy of old code in case I messed something up while experimenting. Your code works.  Thank you!

Comment: If you want to try with your old code you can make your binary fixed with, your format will currently drop the leading 0's. You can set this to be a fixed width of 8 using `y = ' '.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in x)`